# Is there a way to disable checkboxes with different names and id, if radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I figured out the solution, but the name attribute must be the same or it won't work. I was thinking of auto-incrementing the id attribute someway, but I had no luck so far. Here's what I have so far(that works):

```js
function ckChange(ckType) {
  var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType.name);

  for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
    if (!ckName[i].checked) {
      ckName[i].disabled = true;
    } else {
      if (ckName[i].checked) {
        ckName[i].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="radio" name="No Past Conditions" id="rb0" onclick="ckChange(this)" />
   <label for="rb0">No Past Conditions </label>
          
 <input type="checkbox" name="No Past Conditions" id="cb1" value="Yes" onclick="ckChange(this)" />
   <label for="cb1">Heart disease </label>

<!-- WORKS GREAT IF NAME IS THE SAME, HOWEVER I WANT TO CHANGE IT IN ORDER FOR READABILITY WHEN I COLLECT THE FORM -->

<!-- this part here doesn't work, bcz the name attrib is different -->
  <input type="checkbox" name="Anemia or other blood disease" id="cb2" value="Yes" />
          <label for="cb2">Anemia or other blood disease</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Severe headaches" id="cb3" value="Yes" />
          <label for="cb3">Severe headaches</label>
</form>
```

Now I tried declaring a checkbox variable to be autoincremented, using the base id name(cb: checkbox) + j(concatenating it I guess?) but that's not the right syntax I think. Code:

```js
var j;
var checkbox = document.getElementById(cb + j);
for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
```

Clearly I know it's wrong but I've searched for hours and I'm really upset. Can you guys help me?

Edit:@shingo.nakanishi answer generates this error
[image: @shingo.nakanishi answer generates this error]

Comment: So do you want to disable all the checkboxes in the page once a radio button has been enabled?

Comment: It sounds like this is basically about selecting multiple specific elements; one way is to assign a common class to them.

Comment: Liad Yogev Exactly!

Comment: Why do you want to change the content of the `name` attribute _"for readability"_? The attribute should identify an `input` and not define how it's displayed anywhere else o.O

Comment: I'm using a third party website that emails forms whenever someone submits them, and I need the name attribute the same as the fields so I can read what users have checked/filled. @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You need put `getElementById` in for loop.
You don't need to declare `var j` twice.

```
for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById(cb + j);
  ...
}
```

If you do not have a `cb` variable, let `cb` be a String literal as below code.

```
for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("cb" + j);
  ...
}
```

Note

This is a bad practice to use id as @Chris G commented.

If you want a good design, you'll need to make a full revision of the code.

Comment: This answer solves the problem but doing this is bad practice; one shouldn't use `id`s based on consecutive numbers. Wrapping the elements and iterating over `document.querySelectorAll('#conditions input')` (or using a `class`) is a much better solution.

Comment: @Chris G can you show me a small reproducible snippet with your solution that could be run? I'm actually a beginner in js and that would help a lot!

Comment: @ChrisG Yes. I know.  But This question wants to know about syntax errors.

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi I posted the result of your answer in my question with a screenshot. It does have syntax errors. You think you can help me with document.querySelectorAll or a similar solution? Thanks

Comment: @suigetsuh17 use `"cb"` not use `cb` as I write, If you do not have a cb variable, let cb be a String.